# Grails API in combination with Native IOS application

Tags: objective-c, api, grails

I currently created a native IOS application, and now I'm working on the grails backend.

I'm a little new to the API concept, so I'm looking for some some good tutorials which cover the following questions:

- How does the authentication from an IOS application to an API works using JSON?
- How can I push a post to the backend using JSON?

I understand how to write an API in grails which can sent a list of a.e. books, but in the mobile app, a user can define his own items (templates in this case). When the user uses his credentials on another phone, his items need to be transferred to the phone. I currently use spring security to authenticate users on the backend application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For implementing the rest API client in your IOS app i'll suggest you to look [to this library](https://github.com/samvermette/SVHTTPRequest).

The authentication method right for your app and your API is not a simple question and depends on what app do and how. The more standard way yo authenticate apps and with API is [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I understand how to write an API in grails which can sent a list of a.e. books, but in the mobile app, a user can define his own items (templates in this case). When the user uses his credentials on another phone, his items need to be transferred to the phone. I currently use spring security to authenticate users on the backend application.

Comment: There is a plugin that implements OAUTH for spring security http://www.springsource.org/spring-security-oauth